# Query returns no result if compared column is NULL

Tags: oracle11g, null, comparison

Suppose I have the following table (t1) in Oracle 11g database with some sample data in it:

```
   LastName    |   MiddleName    |    FirstName
```

---

```
   Spencer           Davids           Mark
   Zola              *NULL*           Francesca
   Myers             Christian        Frank
   Bugatti           *NULL*           Ziona
```

When I run the following query I expect to get all the 4 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE MiddleName<>'Mikola';
```

But I get only 2 records. The ones where MiddleName is null are not retrieved. So comparing Null and 'Mikola' does not work as I would expect it to. Null does not indeed equals 'Mikola', so what is the problem. As a workaround I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE MiddleName<>'Mikola' or MiddleName is NUll;
```

I don't remember facing this issue before. Is this a new behavior with 11g or has it always been so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior occurred earlier (do not know if it was always). See explanation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm

You can try this: SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE NVL(MiddleName, 'NULL') <>'Mikola';

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE MiddleName not in ('Mikola');
```